# How do I force YouTube to always use the arrow keys for playback seeking?

Tags: youtube

If I changed the volume before using the arrow keys, the arrow keys will change the volume instead of seek playback (skip back and forth 5 seconds). How do I remove this behaviour and make it so it always seeks playback? I am aware of the j and l hotkeys for 10 second seek but I want to use the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the video at least once to start with (so the up and down keys don't scroll the page)
2. Use the up and down keys to adjust volume.
3. Use the left and right keys to seek.

Answer (score -1):

If you're in full screen, just click the top or bottom of your screen and it won't pause the video and does the job too.